# iPhone - Center Map until it gets full accuracy

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I'm making an app and when opening it I start getting userlocation and centering the map to the user location:

```
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Then I have

```
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    location = newLocation.coordinate;

    if (isOpening) {

        //Center location and set zoom on user when opening the app
        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center = location;

        //Set Zoom level using Span
        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        span.latitudeDelta = .005;
        span.longitudeDelta = .005;
        region.span = span;

        isOpening = NO;

        [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE]; 
    }


}
```

Using the isOpening flag, the map stops centering before it gets full accuracy but if I don't set the flag the map keeps centering over and over. Is there a way to get the location and center the map with full accuracy and then stop centering it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[userLocation.location.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (locationAge > 5.0) return;
    if (userLocation.location.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;

    CLLocation *location = userLocation.location;
    static BOOL found = NO;
    if (location && !found) {
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,1000,1000);
        [ridesMap setRegion:region animated:YES];
        found = YES;
    }//end if

}//end
```

Comment: So this will wait 5 seconds until get a nice accuraccy or if it get its earlier it stops. Am I right?

Comment: This is not working fine. The map centers to the user location but what I want is to center the screen the first time but if the user location updates stop moving the map.

Comment: Center the screen? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean. Center the map on the user location but stop doing this when the user moves the map. Like it happens in the Google Maps app.